# Can an object have 2 active snapshots?

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

According to [this](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual) page in the docs, only one snapshot can be active for a given object. However, I seem to have a Defect with 2 active snapshots. All snapshots are shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

As you can, see I have connected the snapshots with arrows and they do not all link together. Is this a bug with Rally or is it in fact possible to have 2 defects with _ValidTo dates in the year 9999?

My query is taken from the example in the docs:

```
URI: https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/12345/artifact/snapshot/query.js
POST data:
{
    "find":  {
       "ObjectID": my funky object
    },
    "fields": ["State", "_ValidFrom", "_ValidTo", "ObjectID", "FormattedID"],
    "hydrate": ["State"],
    "compress": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The object should not have two current snapshots with `_ValidTo` set to `9999-01-01`. Please contact CA Agile Central (Rally) support, and they will raise the issue with the LookbackAPI team, which I believe has a way of fixing the data on their end.